# Minified react error 130 for the full message in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning `react-native` programming, my below program is working well if I remove button, when I add button then it gives an error.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  registerComponent,
} from 'react-native-playground';
import {
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Alert,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

class TextInputDemo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, marginLeft:10, marginTop:40}}>

        <Text>Name</Text>
        <TextInput style={{height:50, flexDirection:'row'}} placeholder="Enter a name" />

        <Text>Age</Text>
        <TextInput style={{height:50, flexDirection:'row'}} placeholder="Enter a age" />

        <Text>Email</Text>
        <TextInput style={{height:50, flexDirection:'row'}} placeholder="Enter a email" />

        <Button title="REGISTER" style={{height:50, flexDirection:'row'}} />

      </View>
    );
  }
};

registerComponent(TextInputDemo);
```

[image]

How can I fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the component incorrectly. It should be:

```
import Button from 'react-native-button';
```

This is because Button.js is exporting the component using export default class instead of module.export. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) regarding export.

Comment: I am getting this error now 'uncaught error:requiring unknown module react-native-button'

Comment: @Williams - have you added "react-native-button" dependencies in your package.json file. If yes then check your compatibility version of.. let me know the after effect

Comment: There is no such file package.json here rnplay.org